# Unable to quit debug/browser mode

Tags: debugging, browser, rstudio

In Rstudio console, I ran the following commands

```
> debug(ls)
> ls()
```

Then, I could not quit/leave the debug mode. I tried the following:

1, "Q" + "enter key" 
2, "c" + "enter key" 
3. the red "Stop" button.

but it does not leave debug mode.

---

```
Browse[2]> Q
debugging in: ls(.Internal(getNamespaceRegistry()), all.names = TRUE)
debug: {
    if (!missing(name)) {
```

---

```
Error: unable to quit when browser is active
Browse[2]> c
exiting from: ls(.Internal(getNamespaceRegistry()), all.names = TRUE)
debugging in: ls(.Internal(getNamespaceRegistry()), all.names = TRUE)
debug: {
    if (!missing(name)) {
```

.....

---

The Rstudio version: Version 0.98.1060 – © 2009-2013 RStudio, Inc.

The R version: R i386.3.1.1

Has anyone had this issue in Rstudio? 
Thanks.
Ang

Comment: I do not have this issue in R console. i.e., I can quit debug mode using "Q"

Answer (score 13):

The problem is that as soon as you leave debug mode, something is triggering a call to `ls`, which puts you back in debug mode. To fix the issue, turn off debugging for `ls` before you leave the debugger:

```
Browse[2]> undebug(ls)
Browse[2]> Q
```

Consider using `debugonce` rather than `debug` to avoid getting into these kinds of loops.